# How to get app icon using package ID for a App which is not installed in Phone- Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, google-play

How to load a image from the play store using the package ID and not from local installed apps. For example when the app is not installed but you need to fetch the icon of the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is an un-official [**API for the Playstore**](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToGetAppScreenshot)

Something like this might work:

```
GetImageRequest imgReq = GetImageRequest.newBuilder().setAppId("-7934792861962808905")
        .setImageUsage(AppImageUsage.ICON)
        .setImageId("1")
        .build();

session.append(imgReq, new Callback<GetImageResponse>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(ResponseContext context, GetImageResponse response) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("icon.png");
            fos.write(response.getImageData().toByteArray());
            fos.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

session.flush();
```

The important part is the `.setImageUsage(AppImageUsage.ICON)` you could also get screenshots with this method, setting `.setImageUsage(AppImageUsage.SCREENSHOT)`

Comment: But what is that AppId?. Its not the package ID??